# Unable to read in / format date data in d3

Tags: d3.js

I would like to be able to read in data of the form below as to plot a scatterplot using d3.
Can someone advise how I would format the 'date' data so that I could plot the daily data on the x axis. A snippet of my code is below.

Data:

```
date    cases

30/04/2020  4956

29/04/2020  5420

28/04/2020  4719

27/04/2020  4699

26/04/2020  3471

25/04/2020  3745
```

Code:

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(data) {

    // List of groups (input data has one group per column)
    var allGroup = ["cases"]

    // add the options to the button
    d3.select("#selectButton")
            .selectAll('myOptions')
            .data(allGroup)
            .enter()
            .append('option')
            .text(function (d) { return d; }) // text shows in the menu
            .attr("value", function (d) { return d; }) // corresponding value returned by the button
            var x = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0,10])
            .range([ 0, width ]);
    svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

    // Add Y axis
    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain( [0,250000])
            .range([ height, 0 ]);
    svg.append("g")
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

    // Initialize line with 'cases'
    var line = svg
            .append('g')
            .append("path")
            .datum(data)
            .attr("d", d3.line()
                    .x(function(d) { return x(+d.time) })
                    .y(function(d) { return y(+d.cases) })
            )
            .attr("stroke", "black")
            .style("stroke-width", 4)
            .style("fill", "none")
```

Many thanks,
Katherine

Comment: Convert CSV data: `const plotData = data.map(({date, cases} => ({date: new Date(date), cases}));`

Comment: Hi @MichaelRovinsky - thanks for your comment. If I understand your response, you're suggesting to format the csv input?  My (limited) understanding is that I need to use a different function to scaleLinear() and that the date column (rather than the csv file) needs to be reformatted once the .csv file is read in.

Comment: Yes, you need to convert the `date` field in the CSV data from `string` to `Date` and use scaleTime for your X axis

Comment: Thank-you @MichaelRovinsky. I'm a newbie to this, would you able to point me to a code snippet/example that I could hack please?

Comment: https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-scaletime